# Preview render resets after rendering a few samples

Tags: rendering

When I enter the rendered shading mode in Cycles the preview render often gets stuck in an infinite loop: it renders a few samples, sometimes only 1, and then restarts from the beginning. I can't find any logic behind which objects or layers need to be visible for this to occur and no settings have changed afaik. This is a recent problem at work, happening in different files on two different computers.

Any ideas what might cause this?

(PS: Since these are work files I'm not allowed to share them here.)

Extra info edit: Blender 2.79. Standard interiors of about 1.5 - 2.5 million faces spread over a handful of layers, nothing we haven't done before.

Comment: Which version of Blender are we talking about? Also, how complex is the file? Vertex count, etc...

Comment: 2.79. Nothing excessive, standard interiors of about 1.5 - 2.5 million faces spread over a handful of layers, nothing we haven't done before.

Comment: Are you playing animation in rendered view?

Comment: As far as I know there are no animations or animated objects in the scenes.

Comment: No matter if any object is animated or not if the timeline cursor is moving then blender takes it as a animation. Are you doing that?

Comment: No, also the amount of samples it renders appears to be somewhat random depending on how many objects or layers it needs to render, so it isn't just rendering a sample per frame for example.